# Date ranges with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date-range

I am trying to create a script that generate date ranges after feeding it an start and end date.

So for example:

> start = 2016-01-01
>
> end = 2017-10-01

The script will output a list like this:

> ['2016-01-01  2016-04-01',
>
> 2016-04-01  2016-07-01',
>
> ‘2016-07-01  2016-10-01',
>
> ‘2016-10-01  2017-01-01',
>
> '2017-01-01  2017-04-01',
>
> ‘2017-04-01  2017-07-01',
>
> ‘2017-07-01  2017-10-01']

So far I have managed generating all the necessary time ranges, but I am having trouble grouping each individual date in to the time format required for these time ranges.

Here is my code so far

```
start = '2016-01-01'
end = str(pd.to_datetime('today').replace(day=1))[:10]
dates = list(pd.date_range(start, end, freq="3MS"))
new_dates = []
for i in dates:
    i= str(i)[:10]
    new_dates.append(i)
```

which outputs this: 
`

```
['2016-01-01',
 '2016-04-01',
 '2016-07-01',
 '2016-10-01',
 '2017-01-01',
 '2017-04-01',
 '2017-07-01',
 '2017-10-01']
```

I greatly appreciated if someone helped me with the last part of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first merge two separate lists into a list of tuples after removing first and last elements respectively (as per answer of @Psidom):

```
dates1 = dates[:-1]
dates2 = dates[1:]
```

This will produce two lists, where `dates1` is missing the last element from the original list, and `dates2` is missing the first element of the original list.

```
dates3 = zip(dates1, dates2)
```

This will produce a structure in `dates3` like this:

```
[('2016-01-01', '2016-04-01'), ('2016-04-01', '2016-07-01'), ...]
```

Now you could generate a list of your desired output strings like this:

```
output = [x + ' ' + y for x,y in dates3]
```

You could also write all this in a single line, but it might hurt readability:

```
output = [x + ' ' + y for x,y in zip(dates[:-1], dates[1:])]
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `dates` array, remove the last element with `dates[:-1]`, remove the first element with `dates[1:]` and then `column_stack` the two arrays:

```
import numpy as np

start = '2016-01-01'
end = pd.to_datetime('today').replace(day=1)
dates = pd.date_range(start, end, freq="3MS").strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

np.column_stack((dates[:-1], dates[1:]))
#array([['2016-01-01', '2016-04-01'],
#       ['2016-04-01', '2016-07-01'],
#       ['2016-07-01', '2016-10-01'],
#       ['2016-10-01', '2017-01-01'],
#       ['2017-01-01', '2017-04-01'],
#       ['2017-04-01', '2017-07-01'],
#       ['2017-07-01', '2017-10-01']], 
#      dtype='<U10')
```

---

To get an entry per range, we can add them up:

```
np.char.add(np.char.add(dates[:-1], ' '), dates[1:])
#array(['2016-01-01 2016-04-01', '2016-04-01 2016-07-01',
#       '2016-07-01 2016-10-01', '2016-10-01 2017-01-01',
#       '2017-01-01 2017-04-01', '2017-04-01 2017-07-01',
#       '2017-07-01 2017-10-01'], 
#      dtype='<U21')
```

Comment: Although here you have arrays with two date objects where the question refers to a single string per range.

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel You're right. Fixed the problem.

Comment: Interesting how that change makes a big impact in the performance.

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel Hmm. `np.char.add` may not be an optimized solution.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a numpy free alternative

```
import pandas as pd

start = '2016-01-01'
end = pd.to_datetime('today').replace(day=1)
dates = pd.date_range(start, end, freq="3MS").strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

coupled_dates = []

for date in zip(*(dates[:-1], dates[1:])):
    coupled_dates.append(' '.join(date))

coupled_dates
```

The caveat here is that it performs about twice as slow as the first `numpy` solution provided by @Psidom. When taking the "propper" second version, `numpy` performs 3 times worse than python.

The advantage is that you could most likely use this solution with the standard `datetime` module in case you don't have access to `pandas`/`numpy`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.date_range("20160101","20171001", freq="3MS") # given date range
b =a.map(str).map(lambda x: x[:10]) # to_string and take 10 characters 
c = b[:-1]+" "+b[1:] # shift the index array and join strings
d = c.tolist() # cast to python's list if you need
```